# How to access *fcmp passed from parameter

Tags: c++

Currently I am working on a merge sort project in my class and am stuck on how to access and utilize the last parameter of this function header:

```
void Mergesort(ItemType* item, size_t nelem, int **(*fcmp) (const ItemType& e1, const ItemType& e2))**
```

Knowing that the result of the comparison will be *-1*, *0*, or *1* but since the parameter itself doesn't have a name, I don't know how to explicitly call the pointer of the function.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pointer to a function, so you can call it like a regular function. For example:

```
fcmp(item[0], item[1]);
```